# NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'path' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: path

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When I pass pdf URL value to this its getting error with the built-in keyword "path" and it seems to be null?

```
loadPdf(String pdfPath) async {
    setState(() => _isLoading = true);

    var fileName = pdfPath.split('/').last;
    
    var localFileUrl = (await Directory(CacheManager.getInstance().appDocumentDir.path +'/'+"realpro"+"/").create(recursive: true)).path +fileName;
    
    if (await CacheManager.getInstance().checkFileExist(localFileUrl)) {
      document = await PDFDocument.fromAsset(localFileUrl);
      print(document);
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    } else {
      document = await PDFDocument.fromURL(pdfPath);
      print(document);
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: please check this link https://github.com/kaisellgren/mailer/issues/89

Answer (score 0):

> The getter 'path' was called on null.

The error means that the object for which you are writing `object.path` is `null`. You can use `?.` operator like this: `object?.something` which is equivalent to:

```
object!=null ? object.something : null
```